# Can't connect to SMTP server

Tags: mailkit

I am trying to get an email service set up for a tool we are building. I am using MailKit, and I am encountering an exception when I attempt to connect to the SMTP server.

```
var message = new MimeMessage();
message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Some Body", "some.body@some-place.com"));
message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Some Body", "some.body@some-place.com"));
message.Subject = "Test Message";
message.Body = new TextPart("plain")
{
    Text = "Test message body"
};

using (var client = new SmtpClient())
{
    client.Connect("x.x.x.x", 25, false);
    client.Send(message);
    client.Disconnect(true);
}
```

I get:

> An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions x.x.x.x:25

And if I dig a little further:

> A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied

I am able to connect to the server and send myself a message using putty from the same computer that I am running this code. It doesn't require authentication. Am I missing something?

I've tried debugging the mailkit library, and the exception occurs here (SocketUtil.cs):

```
                try {
                    if (localEndPoint != null)
                        socket.Bind (localEndPoint);

#if NETSTANDARD_2_0 || NET_4_5 || NET_4_6 || NET_4_7 || __MOBILE__
                    if (doAsync || cancellationToken.CanBeCanceled) {
                        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool> ();

                        using (var registration = cancellationToken.Register (() => tcs.TrySetCanceled (), false)) {
                            var ar = socket.BeginConnect (ipAddresses[i], port, e => tcs.TrySetResult (true), null);

                            if (doAsync)
                                await tcs.Task.ConfigureAwait (false);
                            else
                                tcs.Task.GetAwaiter ().GetResult ();

                            socket.EndConnect (ar);
                        }
                    } else {
                        socket.Connect (ipAddresses[i], port);
                    }
#else
                    socket.Connect (ipAddresses[i], port);
#endif

                    return socket;
                } catch (OperationCanceledException) {
                    socket.Dispose ();
                    throw;
                } catch {
                    socket.Dispose ();

                    if (i + 1 == ipAddresses.Length)
                        throw;
                }
            }

            throw new IOException (string.Format ("Failed to resolve host: {0}", host));
        }
```

Curiously, the code is going through the `#if NETSTANDARD_2_0 || NET_4_5 || NET_4_6 || NET_4_7 || __MOBILE__` block rather than the `else` statement. I don't think I have any of those defined. I am running mailkit in a dotnet core 3.0 MVC web application.

Comment: Try debugging this by building MailKit from source and stepping through https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/MailKit/Net/SocketUtils.cs#L38

Comment: @jstedfast see edit, thanks!

Comment: The #if's are decided not based on what you have defined in YOUR app, it's decided based on what is defined in MailKit. If you are using DotNetCore, then you are likely using the netstandard2.0 version of MailKit.

Comment: Which line fails? What are the values of the variables being used? e.g. what is the value of `ipAddresses[i]`?

Comment: @jstedfast So `host` and `port` are both correct (can't write them here), `localEndpoint = null` (which I think is fine), `doAsync = false` and `ipAddress[i] == host`. The exception occurs when running `EndConnect`. At that point, it jumps to the catch block.

Comment: Which catch block? OperationCanceledException?

Comment: @jstedfast nope, the second one. Operation isn't cancelled.

Comment: @jstedfast I just created an empty MVC core 2.2 project, added the MailkitProject and reference, and it gives me the same exception as above when running the same code. I used the "NetStandard" project.

Comment: What if you use a .NET45 project? Does that work? This code works flawlessly for me no matter what framework I use, so I don't understand why it is failing for you unless you are getting blocked by a firewall or something. There's also no datagram sending (that would be UDP), so the exception you are getting makes no sense.

Comment: @jstedfast If your talking about the second exception, I'm pretty sure it's a generic message for both TCP and UDP. It's just specifying that in the case of UDP if the socket isnt connected, you have to supply an endpoint when sending. I'll try right away with 4.5

Comment: @jstedfast Same result...

Comment: @jstedfast Very frustrating... I just tried in our "deployed" dev server, and it works just fine. When testing on my local machine, the above happens... As I mentioned I don't know why since I can access the smtp server through telnet on that very same machine... So it looks like the library is fine, just something wrong with my machine though I have no idea what..